# What is killing this process and how to stop it from doing so

Tags: php, linux, bash, apache, centos

As part of a process automation routine I have a shell script which executes several PHP scripts via CLI. One of them, the very last of course, is very, very long. The code base I was handed was a mess and much of the import.php script and ImportProduct.php object is essentially unmodifiable.

Last week I finished updating the code to MySQLi and set to testing and keep getting a similar process termination message. I have dug through the Magento PHP library, my own code, the original code and can find nothing which would cause it. The format alone lends one to believe that either the PHP CLI interpreter, Linux OS, or Apache (if it is even running via Apache, sadly not very sysadmin savvy) is causing the termination. I SSH to the remote server, but the last two lines show that SSH itself did not timeout.

The default timeout via PHP CLI is that there is none, however setting it to 0 or 180 days makes no difference. Therefore, I believe the issue is at a lower level. *Please don't bother screaming about root access it's not my decision to work this way.*

Here is a section of my messages. Line 5 contains the termination message.

```
new_import_products.php: ET068FII.TXT: Processed 406085 records in 1686 queries. 
import.php: Begin
ImportProduct.php> start 1055398
import.php: done loadFile()
./executeFullUpdateImport.sh: line 58: 4908 Killed php -f import.php
executeFullUpdateImport> full update/import completed
executeFullUpdateImport> Performed in 384m, 56s.\n\n
[root@stinedev import]# 
[root@stinedev import]# ls
```

Searching for something like this was very unhelpful. Google returns 9 billion pages of how to kill a process... not keep one alive, no matter what combinations of terms I use (admittedly I could be asking the wrong questions).

Comment: Chances are it's the linux OOM killer - out-of-memory. I'd bet your script does some sort of `foreach` that doesn't clean up its variables after each iteration, and that the more items it processes the more RAM it uses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory

Comment: Will it be written to syslog @ceejayoz ?

Comment: I will be leaving the output dump up to the client. Right now it simply outputs to stdout/stderr. The shell script itself is nothing more than a bunch of calls to other files, ie a couple other shell scripts, jar files and php files. There are no variables at all. I was very careful in the PHP code to eliminate globals, and even member variables, and make certain the MySQL resources were released ASAP.

Comment: Typically yes, OOM would show up in syslog somewhere.

Comment: @ceejayoz After finding it, /var/log/messages[-date], I did find an OOM message. I'm going to guess that this is what I needed to find: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d667e8455adfe728e838

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was that it is indeed an Out-of-Memory (OOM) error. Wish the message was more descriptive when it was killed.

The log file is platform dependant, but on CentOS it was located at:

```
/var/log/messages[-date]
```

where [-date] is an optional YYYYMMDD date stamp. The offending entries will look something like this:

```
... some log stuff here ...
Apr 13 21:26:23 MACHINE kernel: php invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Apr 13 21:26:23 MACHINE kernel: php cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Apr 13 21:26:23 MACHINE kernel: Pid: 1337, comm: php Not tainted 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1
Apr 13 21:26:23 MACHINE kernel: Call Trace:
... more log stuff here ...
```

where MACHINE is the name of your rig.

PS: Thanks for the help in the comments. I wouldn't of been able to answer this without the help, and would of chose an answer from them, but it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this situation. One possible cause is oom killer. That's easy to check. dmsg will print this behavior.
As some other user process send signal to kill,my solution is to use  kernel audition. google auditctl the first entry.

Comment: If you were to flesh this out a bit I would accept it as the answer, but sans some explanation it's too vague.